# How to set LocalNotification repeat each two minutes?

Tags: iphone, repeat, localnotification

I'm using LocalNotication to set schedule Alarm. atribute repeatInterval allow me to set repeat each minute, each hour.. But I want to set repeat each two minutes? How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looking at this blog posting

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule 30 alarms. One for each 2nd minute for a whole hour, and set repeatInterval to each hour fo each of the 30 notifications.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i just want to know if the framework support this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a bug report/enhancement at http://bugreport.apple.com/

You may take a look at my report archived at Open Radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=759402

According to Marco, developer of Instapaper, Apple prioritizes enhancement and feature requests partly based on how many developers are requesting them.

If this feature is important to you I urge you to file a report as well.